# Pie plot getting its text on top of each other

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just trying to fix this overlapped labeling:

[image]

My code:

```
  values=c(164241,179670)
  labels=c("Private", "Public")
  colors=c("#cccccc", "#aaaaaa")
  categoriesName="Access"
  percent_str <- paste(round(graph$values / sum(graph$values) * 100,1), "%", sep="")

  values <- data.frame(val = graph$values, Type = graph$labels, percent=percent_str )

  pie <- ggplot(values, aes(x = "", y = val, fill = Type)) + geom_bar(width = 1) + 
          geom_text(aes(y = **val + 1**, **hjust=0.5**, **vjust=-0.5**, label = percent), colour="#333333", face="bold", size=10) +
          coord_polar(theta = "y") + ylab(NULL) + xlab(NULL) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = graph$colors) + labs(fill = graph$categoriesName) +
          opts( title = graph$title, 
                axis.text.x = NULL,
                plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"), 
                plot.title = theme_text(face="bold", size=14), 
                panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA) )
  print(pie)
```

Tried messing with the values marked with asterisks (** **) but haven't got anywhere.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here is an example:

```
pie <- ggplot(values, aes(x = "", y = val, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = val/2 + c(0, cumsum(val)[-length(val)]), label = percent), size=10)
pie + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]

Perhaps this will help you understand how it work:

```
pie + coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = seq(1, sum(values$val), length = 10), label = letters[1:10]))
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to place them more on the outside? increase the text radius.

Comment: try `geom_text(aes(x = 1.3, y = ...`

Comment: I really thought I understood your logic until I tried a more complex example :D this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/E5rsC.png for this values: c(81805,78424,19441), labels c("Singapore", "Unknown", "Other") and y = val/2 + c(0, cumsum(val)[-length(val)]) because it made sense. any pointers?

Comment: ah, it should be like this: `y = sum(val)-(val/2 + c(0, cumsum(val)[-length(val)]))`

Comment: yes, that was it. thanks! just a minor question to finish... is there any way to apply map the label size to the value? I need smaller text in a small pie.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if it worked or not. We can see that the size is probably proportional. I tried using a formula like 5+percent*5 for the size, to no luck. Also the grouping on the right, shouldn't happen.