# geom_text evaluation using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, facet, geom-text

I need to plot three pie charts using the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=5),
                 var = rep(letters[1:5], 3),
                 value = c(10, 8, 6, 4, 2))
```

This code produce the type of chart I want:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = var, weight=value)) +
    geom_bar(width = 1.2, colour = "white") +
    coord_polar(theta="y") +
    facet_wrap( ~ id)
```

[image]

The problem arise when I need to add some text to label each slice of the pie:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = var, weight=value)) +
    geom_bar(width = 1.2, colour = "white") +
    coord_polar(theta="y") +
    geom_text(aes(x = 1.8, y=rowMeans(embed(c(0,cumsum(value)),2)),
                  label=sprintf("%.1f", value)), size = 5, colour = "grey25") +
    facet_wrap( ~ id)
```

[image]

It seems that `rowMeans(embed(c(0,cumsum(value)),2))` is not evaluated against the portion of data being displayed by each facet (as I would expect).

Having created a very trivial case, the positions should be always the same:

```
> rowMeans(embed(c(0,cumsum(df$value[ df$id == "A"])),2))
[1]  5 14 21 26 29
> rowMeans(embed(c(0,cumsum(df$value[ df$id == "B"])),2))
[1]  5 14 21 26 29
> rowMeans(embed(c(0,cumsum(df$value[ df$id == "C"])),2))
[1]  5 14 21 26 29
```

**Q:** What is actually `ggplot` doing when evaluating the above expression?

Comment: I can't answer what exactly `ggplot` does, but in case you haven't tried this, first calculating the y's (storing them in a new column of df) and then calling ggplot referencing that column (instead of the formula) works. Eg `df <- ddply(df, .(id), transform, v = rowMeans(embed(c(0,cumsum(value)),2)))` and then using the same statement you have with `y=v` in `geom_text`.

Comment: @Michelle Didn't my anwer work? I was just wondering because you didn't accept it. If it didn't, I like to know what was wrong, so I can improve on it.

Comment: @Jaap It worked indeed! I really don't know why I didn't vote nor accept it months ago. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's better to achieve the desired result by creating a position variable (as I also showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-piechart-slices/22804400#22804400)). Applying this method to your situation:

```
# creating the position variable
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(pos=cumsum(value) - 0.5*value)

# creating the plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = var, weight=value)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1.2, colour = "white") +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.8, y=pos, label=sprintf("%.1f", value)), size = 5, colour = "grey25") +
  facet_wrap( ~ id)
```

which gives:
[image]