# R: Pie chart with percentage as labels using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, label

From a data frame I want to plot a pie chart for five categories with their percentages as labels in the same graph in order from highest to lowest, going clockwise.

My code is:

```
League<-c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A","E","D","A","D")
data<-data.frame(League) # I have more variables 

p<-ggplot(data,aes(x="",fill=League))
p<-p+geom_bar(width=1)
p<-p+coord_polar(theta="y")
p<-p+geom_text(data,aes(y=cumsum(sort(table(data)))-0.5*sort(table(data)),label=paste(as.character(round(sort(table(data))/sum(table(data)),2)),rep("%",5),sep="")))
p
```

I use

```
cumsum(sort(table(data)))-0.5*sort(table(data))
```

to place the label in the corresponding portion and

```
label=paste(as.character(round(sort(table(data))/sum(table(data)),2)),rep("%",5),sep="")
```

for the labels which is the percentages.

I get the following output:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot, facet, piechart: placing text in the middle of pie chart slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've preserved most of your code. I found this pretty easy to debug by leaving out the `coord_polar`... easier to see what's going on as a bar graph.

The main thing was to reorder the factor from highest to lowest to get the plotting order correct, then just playing with the label positions to get them right. I also simplified your code for the labels (you don't need the `as.character` or the `rep`, and `paste0` is a shortcut for `sep = ""`.)

```
League<-c("A","B","A","C","D","E","A","E","D","A","D")
data<-data.frame(League) # I have more variables 

data$League <- reorder(data$League, X = data$League, FUN = function(x) -length(x))

at <- nrow(data) - as.numeric(cumsum(sort(table(data)))-0.5*sort(table(data)))

label=paste0(round(sort(table(data))/sum(table(data)),2) * 100,"%")

p <- ggplot(data,aes(x="", fill = League,fill=League)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  annotate(geom = "text", y = at, x = 1, label = label)
p
```

The `at` calculation is finding the centers of the wedges. (It's easier to think of them as the centers of bars in a stacked bar plot, just run the above plot without the `coord_polar` line to see.) The `at` calculation can be broken out as follows:

`table(data)` is the number of rows in each group, and `sort(table(data))` puts them in the order they'll be plotted. Taking the `cumsum()` of that gives us the edges of each bar when stacked on top of each other, and multiplying by 0.5 gives us the half the heights of each bar in the stack (or half the widths of the wedges of the pie).

`as.numeric()` simply ensures we have a numeric vector rather than an object of class `table`.

Subtracting the half-widths from the cumulative heights gives the centers each bar when stacked up. But ggplot will stack the bars with the biggest on the bottom, whereas all our `sort()`ing puts the smallest first, so we need to do `nrow -` everything because what we've actually calculate are the label positions relative to the *top* of the bar, not the bottom. (And, with the original disaggregated data, `nrow()` is the total number of rows hence the total height of the bar.)

Comment: thank you very much!! I was going crazy to do this. I'm noob with the ggplot2 library.

Comment: @Gregor could you please explain what your code is doing when calculating `at`? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @info_seekeR added a few paragraphs at the bottom, see if that helps.

Comment: @Gregor very clear and understandable - thank you! :)

Answer (score 10):

Preface: I did not make pie charts of my own free will.

Here's a modification of the `ggpie` function that includes percentages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#
# df$main should contain observations of interest
# df$condition can optionally be used to facet wrap
#
# labels should be a character vector of same length as group_by(df, main) or
# group_by(df, condition, main) if facet wrapping
#

pie_chart <- function(df, main, labels = NULL, condition = NULL) {

  # convert the data into percentages. group by conditional variable if needed
  df <- group_by_(df, .dots = c(condition, main)) %>%
    summarize(counts = n()) %>%
    mutate(perc = counts / sum(counts)) %>%
    arrange(desc(perc)) %>%
    mutate(label_pos = cumsum(perc) - perc / 2,
           perc_text = paste0(round(perc * 100), "%"))

  # reorder the category factor levels to order the legend
  df[[main]] <- factor(df[[main]], levels = unique(df[[main]]))

  # if labels haven't been specified, use what's already there
  if (is.null(labels)) labels <- as.character(df[[main]])

  p <- ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = factor(1), y = "perc", fill = main)) +

    # make stacked bar chart with black border
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", width = 1) +

    # add the percents to the interior of the chart
    geom_text(aes(x = 1.25, y = label_pos, label = perc_text), size = 4) +

    # add the category labels to the chart
    # increase x / play with label strings if labels aren't pretty
    geom_text(aes(x = 1.82, y = label_pos, label = labels), size = 4) +

    # convert to polar coordinates
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +

    # formatting
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "", labels = unique(labels)) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 22),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank())

  # facet wrap if that's happening
  if (!is.null(condition)) p <- p + facet_wrap(condition)

  return(p)
}
```

Example:

```
# sample data
resps <- c("A", "A", "A", "F", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E")
cond <- c(rep("cat A", 5), rep("cat B", 4))
example <- data.frame(resps, cond)
```

Just like a typical ggplot call:

```
ex_labs <- c("alpha", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot")

pie_chart(example, main = "resps", labels = ex_labs) +
  labs(title = "unfacetted example")
```

[image: Unfacetted pie chart abomination]

```
ex_labs2 <- c("alpha", "charlie", "foxtrot", "delta", "charlie", "echo")

pie_chart(example, main = "resps", labels = ex_labs2, condition = "cond") +
  labs(title = "facetted example")
```

[image]

Comment: This is some great coding. I am having issues with all of the solutions where my chart seems to be built counterclockwise, but my labels are clockwise? Thanks

Comment: I tried changing direction of the polar with `direction=-1` but it seems to flip both the percents and direction so I get the same issue

Comment: Solved it @Reno. I changed the following line `label_pos = sum(perc) - cumsum(perc) + perc / 2`

Comment: worked for me with a ``1-(cumsum(perc)-perc/2).`` Also useful is ``theme_void()``

Answer (score 0):

It worked on all included function greatly inspired from [here](http://mathematicalcoffee.blogspot.fr/2014/06/ggpie-pie-graphs-in-ggplot2.html)

```
 ggpie <- function (data) 
{
  # prepare name
  deparse( substitute(data) ) -> name ;

  # prepare percents for legend
  table( factor(data) ) -> tmp.count1
  prop.table( tmp.count1 ) * 100 -> tmp.percent1 ;
  paste( tmp.percent1, " %", sep = "" ) -> tmp.percent2 ;
  as.vector(tmp.count1) -> tmp.count1 ;

  # find breaks for legend
  rev( tmp.count1 ) -> tmp.count2 ;
  rev( cumsum( tmp.count2 ) - (tmp.count2 / 2) ) -> tmp.breaks1 ;

  # prepare data
  data.frame( vector1 = tmp.count1, names1 = names(tmp.percent1) ) -> tmp.df1 ;


  # plot data
  tmp.graph1 <- ggplot(tmp.df1, aes(x = 1, y = vector1, fill = names1 ) ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black" ) +
    guides( fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list( colour = NA ) ) ) +
    coord_polar( theta = "y" ) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text( colour = "black"),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text( hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5) ) +
    scale_y_continuous( breaks = tmp.breaks1, labels = tmp.percent2 ) +   
    ggtitle( name ) + 
    scale_fill_grey( name = "") ;

  return( tmp.graph1 )
} ;
```

An example :

```
sample( LETTERS[1:6], 200, replace = TRUE) -> vector1 ;
ggpie(vector1)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AVQq.png)