# Trying to fill large gap in pie chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, pie-chart

Attempting to create pie chart with ggplot2 but cannot seem to get it using other references online. The chart I create is missing most of its fill.

```
ggplot(sae,aes(x=1,fill=factor(State), width=1))+        
geom_bar()+
ggtitle("House by State")+
coord_polar(theta='y')
```

This code gives:

[image]

How do I fill the center?

Any other improvements appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)?

Comment: Piecharts are bad. But you can use `x=factor(1)` if you really want one.

Comment: @Heroka Using `1` or `factor(1)` doesn't make a difference. What I'm missing is an `y` inside the `aes`.

Comment: @Jaap I made some sample data based on some assumptions on what the data looked like. Worked on my machine, with my assumptions. geom_bar doesn't have `y` as a required aesthetic.

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_polar.html

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices/22804400#22804400) for making a (faceted) pie-chart.

Comment: working on a reproducible example right now.

Comment: But I will repeat myself. Piecharts are bad. What is wrong with a (stacked) barchart? [hope this is not a paywall](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.6549/abstract?campaign=woletoc)

Comment: @Heroka Completely agree that pie-charts are bad, I dedicated an answer to that.

Comment: @Jaap I will edit my answer with some more examples. Hard to differentiate between 'interesting programming puzzle!' and 'people should stop doing this'...

Answer (score 5):

With sample data

```
sae <- data.frame(State=sample(LETTERS[1:6],60,T))

                  
ggplot(sae,aes(x=factor(1),fill=factor(State)))+        
  geom_bar(width=1)+
  ggtitle("House by State")+
  coord_polar(theta="y")
```

[image]

## EDIT: Other options (because piecharts are bad)

```
#following Jaaps example: some better way to visualize this
#grouped barchart

p1 <- ggplot(sae, aes(x=State, fill=State)) +
  geom_bar() + labs(title="grouped barchart")


#stacked barchart; especially practical if you want to compare groups
sae$group <- rbinom(60,1,0.5)
p2 <- ggplot(sae, aes(x=factor(group),fill=State))+
  geom_bar(width=0.5) + labs(title="grouped stacked barchart")

do.call(grid.arrange,list(grobs=list(p1,p2),ncol=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer, +1. Keep in mind though that this way of constructing piecharts (without specifying `y`) only works for factor variables.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm trying to think of situations of pie-charts with continuous y-axis. And I should stop thinking about piecharts (and continue my thesis).

Answer (score 2):

As @Heroka already mentioned in the comments, pie-charts are a bad way of visualizing information. They are bad that it is even mentioned in the help-files of R.

From `?pie`:

> Pie charts are a very bad way of displaying information. The eye is
>   good at judging linear measures and bad at judging relative areas. A
>   bar chart or dot chart is a preferable way of displaying this type of
>   data.
>
> Cleveland (1985), page 264: “Data that can be shown by pie charts
>   always can be shown by a dot chart. This means that judgements of
>   position along a common scale can be made instead of the less accurate
>   angle judgements.” This statement is based on the empirical
>   investigations of Cleveland and McGill as well as investigations by
>   perceptual psychologists.

[Some further reading on the pie-chart debate](http://vizthinker.com/grudge-match-pie-chart-vs-bar-chart/).

---

With the example data of @Heroka:

```
ggplot(sae,aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(State)))+        
  geom_bar(width = 1, position = "dodge")+
  ggtitle("House by State")
```

you get:

[image]

A clear demonstration that it's better to see the differences between the categories when you use a barchart instead of a piechart.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to show information about proportions, there is another choice, the **waffle** package which gets back more to what you probably intend to show with a pie chart (i.e., proportions). In most instances, the bar plots above would likely be best, but for the sake of showing another way of plotting...

Using the `sae` data from above:

```
library(waffle)  # install the package if you don't have it
w <- table(sae)
w.waf <- waffle(table(sae))
w.waf + ggtitle("Contextless Waffle Graph") + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=24))
```

which yields this:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! You could probably do this in ggplot with geom_tile() as well, with some reshaping of the data and tweaking of the theme.

Comment: Nice alternative plot. +1