# Plotting multiple Pie Charts with label in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pie-chart

I came across this question the other day and tried to re-create it for myself. [ggplot, facet, piechart: placing text in the middle of pie chart slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices)
. My data is in a very similar format, but sadly the accepted answer did not help, hence why I am re posting.

I essentially want to create the accepted answer but with my own data, yet the issue I run into is that `coord_polar does not support free scale`. Using the first answer: 
[image: test_pie]

I tried it using the second version of the answer, with the ddplyr version, but I also do not get my desired output.  Using the second answer:
[image: test_pie2]

Clearly none of these has the desired effect. I would prefer to create one as with size pie charts, but only showed four as an example, follows: [image: desired_pie].
This I did in excel, but with one legend, and no background grid.

**Code**

```
title<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)
type<-c('A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B')
value<-c(0.25,0.75,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.15,0.85)

piec<-data.frame(title,type,value)
library(tidyverse)    

p1<-ggplot(data = piec, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") 
  #facet_grid(title ~ ., scales = "free")
p1


piec <- piec %>% group_by(title) %>% mutate(pos=cumsum(value)-0.5*value)
p2<-ggplot(data = piec) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = "", y = value, fill = type), stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x = "", y = pos, label = value)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") 
  #facet_grid(Channel ~ ., scales = "free") 
p2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to supply different y values for `geom_text` and `geom_bar` (use `y = value` for both of them). Next you have to specify position in `geom_text`. Finally, remove `scales` from facets.

```
library(ggplot2)

title<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)
type<-c('A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B')
value<-c(0.25,0.75,0.3,0.7,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.15,0.85)
piec<-data.frame(title,type,value)

ggplot(piec, aes("", value, fill = type)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white", size = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value * 100, "%")), 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
              color = "white", size = 3) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    facet_wrap(~ title, ncol = 3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0048cc", "#cc8400")) +
    theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay. I know I did not specify this, in which case forget it, but anyway to remove the white lines on the pie charts? replace them with nothing?

Comment: @JackArmstrong in the `geom_bar` part remove `color = white`