# ggplot2 geom_text position in pie chart

Tags: ggplot2, pie-chart, geom-text

I am plotting pie charts with ggplot2 and succeeded in having the percentage-labels centered in each slice

```
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library("readxl")
df <- read_excel("Radiocomp.xlsx")

df$Pattern <- factor(cc$Pattern)
str(cc)

GGO <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = "", y = GGO, fill = Pattern)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(GGO, "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar("y") +
  theme_void()

GGO
```

[Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFjNz.jpg)

I try to place the percent-label outside the pie for better readability

Any recommendation?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved by setting the `x` aesthetic inside `geom_text`, e.g. `x = 1.6` will put the label just outside of the pie.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# example data
mpg1 <- mpg %>% 
  count(class) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n))

ggplot(mpg1, aes(x = "", y = pct, fill = class)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.6, label = scales::percent(pct, accuracy = .1)), position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
  coord_polar("y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable feedback. Adding x aesthetic inside geom_text almost worked, however x values below 2 cause donuts and displaced labels and x values above 2 place the labels too far outside the chart.

Comment: Hi @xray_mash. That's the way it is. (; But to the best of my knowledge this is by far the simplest solution. For a lengthy discussion on drawing pie charts and setting labels see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices. BTW: Positioning labels always requires some manual work and tweaking.