# I want to add the count percentage for each category as a label to my ggplot pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am using the code:

```
age_pie_chart <- ggplot(data = data , aes(x = "", fill = `Q1: How old are you?`))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", width = 1) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y") + xlab("") + ylab("") +  blank_theme + scale_fill_grey()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
age_pie_chart
```

I want the percentage of each category to be added inside the chart.
from searching I understand that I need to use geom_text function but before that I need to construct a frequency table with the percentage of the count of each category.

[image: this is the pie chart]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 geom\_text position in pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173825/ggplot2-geom-text-position-in-pie-chart)

Comment: For construct the frequency table - it would be best if you can provide a reproducible data. with `dput` some sample of the data you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with some dummy data.  First, here's the dummy data.  I'm using `sample()` to select values and then I'm ensuring we have a "small" slice by adding only 2 values for `Q1 = "-15"`.

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(
  Q1 = c(sample(c('15-7','18-20','21-25'), 98, replace=TRUE), rep('-15', 2))
)
```

For the plot, it's basically the same as your plot, although you don't need the `width` argument for `geom_bar()`.

To get the text positioned correctly, you'll want to use `geom_text()`.  You could calculate the frequency before plotting, or you could have `ggplot` calculate that on the fly much like it did for `geom_bar` by using `stat="count"` for your `geom_text()` layer.

library(ggplot2)

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x="", fill=Q1)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill") +
  geom_text(
    stat='count', 
    aes(y=after_stat(..count..),
        label=after_stat(scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..),1))),
    position=position_fill(0.5),
  ) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

So to be clear what's going on in that `geom_text()` line:

- **I'm using `stat="count"`**.  We want to access that counting statistic within the plot, so we need to specify to use that special stat function.
- **We are using `..count..` within the aesthetics.**  The key here is that in order to access the `..count..` value, we need the stat function to compute first.  You can use the `after_stat()` function to specify that the stat function should happen first before mapping the aesthetics - that opens `..count..` up to use for use within `aes()`!
- **Percent calculation for the label.** This happens via `..count../sum(..count..)`.  I'm using `scales::percent()` as a way to format the label as a percent.
- **Position = fill**.  Like the bar geom, we are also needing to use `position="fill"`.  You need to specify to use the actual `position_fill()` method, since it allows us to access the `vjust` argument.  This positions each text value in the "middle" of each slice.  If you just set `position="fill"`, you get the text positioned at the edge of each slice.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question, I tried the code and it worked :D