# Tidying up the ggplot pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

After looking at various post and asking questions here i have been able to make a multi faceted pie chart. But i am facing a problem in tidying up the pie chart. Here are the things i am having troubles with:

1. **How do i remove the facet labels from each row and only have one facet label on the top or bottom and left or right? How do i control how the facet label looks?**

- I have tried using `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap` and that removes the label from each row but still the labels are inside a box. I would like to remove the box which i donot seem to be able to do.

2. **Centering the labels so that the values for each fraction of the pie is inside that pie-slice.**
   Some of my piechart have 8 to 10 values and they are not always inside there fraction. First i used `geom_text_repel` but that only helped me to repel the text. It didnt place the text inside each fraction. I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices) thread. I tried that by creating a new dataframe which has a position values and using that `pos` inside `geom_text` like so `d<-c %>% group_by(Parameter)%>% mutate(pos= ave(Values, Zones, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x) - 0.5 * x))` and using the same code to make pie chart for `d` dataframe but it didnt quite work.
3. **Grouping the values under certain level into one single "other" groups so the number of slices would be less**
   It would be ideal for me to be able to group the values with less than 1 % into one single group and call it "others" so that the number of slices are less. So far i have to completely ignore those values by `c<-c[c$Values>1,]` and using this newly created data frame.

Any suggestions/help regarding these issues would be helpful.
Following is the reproducible example of my current pie chart:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
my_pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))

#### create new matrix ############
new_mat<-matrix(, nrow=40, ncol = 4)
colnames(new_mat)<-c("Zones", "ssoilcmb", "Erosion_t", "area..sq.m.")


for ( i in 1:nrow(new_mat)){ 
  new_mat[i,4]<-as.numeric(sample(0:20, 1))
  new_mat[i,3]<-as.numeric(sample(0:20, 1))
  a<-sample(c("S2","S3","S4","S5","S1"),1)
  b<-sample(c("Deep","Moderate","Shallow"),1)
  new_mat[i,1]<-sample(c("High Precip","Moderate Precip","Low Precip"),1)
  
  new_mat[i,2]<-paste0(a,"_",b)
}

m_dt<-as.data.frame(new_mat)
m_dt$Erosion_t<-as.numeric(m_dt$Erosion_t)
m_dt$area..sq.m.<-as.numeric(m_dt$area..sq.m.)

#### calculate parea
m_dt<- m_dt %>%
  group_by(Zones)%>%
  mutate(per_er=signif((`Erosion_t`/sum(`Erosion_t`))*100,3), per_area=signif((`area..sq.m.`/sum(`area..sq.m.`))*100,3))

## Rearranging data:

a<-data.frame(m_dt$Zones,m_dt$ssoilcmb, m_dt$per_er)
b<-data.frame(m_dt$Zones,m_dt$ssoilcmb, m_dt$per_area)
c<-data.frame(Zones=m_dt$Zones,ssoilcmb=m_dt$ssoilcmb,
              Parameter=c(rep("Erosion",40),rep("Area",40)),
              Values=c(m_dt$per_er,m_dt$per_area))

### New Plot ###

ggplot(c, aes(x="", y=Values, fill=ssoilcmb)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, position = position_fill())+
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  facet_wrap(Zones~Parameter, nrow = 3) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = paste0(Values, "%")), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=my_pal(15)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, title = "Erosions")+
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                          axis.text = element_blank(),
                          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#666666"))
```

Comment: Your example did not work for me when I tried to run it. Regardless, if you're open to alternatives: http://varianceexplained.org/r/improving-pie-chart/

Comment: @jared_mamrot I forgot to include two libraries into the code. I tried to run it in different computer after including the library and it worked fine for me? I hope you have the Rcolorbrewer library.

Comment: All good. Thanks for fixing the example - it definitely helps your chances of getting a solution to your problem when you make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to alternatives, maybe a facet_wrapped barplot will suit your needs, e.g.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)

my_pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))

#### create new matrix ############
new_mat<-matrix(nrow=40, ncol = 4)
colnames(new_mat)<-c("Zones", "ssoilcmb", "Erosion_t", "area..sq.m.")


for ( i in 1:nrow(new_mat)){ 
  new_mat[i,4]<-as.numeric(sample(0:20, 1))
  new_mat[i,3]<-as.numeric(sample(0:20, 1))
  a<-sample(c("S2","S3","S4","S5","S1"),1)
  b<-sample(c("Deep","Moderate","Shallow"),1)
  new_mat[i,1]<-sample(c("High Precip","Moderate Precip","Low Precip"),1)
  
  new_mat[i,2]<-paste0(a,"_",b)
}

m_dt<-as.data.frame(new_mat)
m_dt$Erosion_t<-as.numeric(m_dt$Erosion_t)
m_dt$area..sq.m.<-as.numeric(m_dt$area..sq.m.)

#### calculate parea
m_dt<- m_dt %>%
  group_by(Zones)%>%
  mutate(per_er=signif((`Erosion_t`/sum(`Erosion_t`))*100,3),
         per_area=signif((`area..sq.m.`/sum(`area..sq.m.`))*100,3))

## Rearranging data:

a<-data.frame(m_dt$Zones,m_dt$ssoilcmb, m_dt$per_er)
b<-data.frame(m_dt$Zones,m_dt$ssoilcmb, m_dt$per_area)
c<-data.frame(Zones=m_dt$Zones,ssoilcmb=m_dt$ssoilcmb,
              Parameter=c(rep("Erosion",40),rep("Area",40)),
              Values=c(m_dt$per_er,m_dt$per_area))

### New Plot ###
c$Zones <- factor(c$Zones,levels(c$Zones)[c(2,3,1)])

ggplot(c, aes(x=ssoilcmb, y=Values, fill=ssoilcmb)) + 
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(Zones~Parameter, nrow = 3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=my_pal(15)) +
  labs(x = NULL, fill = NULL, title = "Erosions")+
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
                          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,
                                                     hjust = 1,
                                                     vjust = 0.5),
                          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                                    color = "#666666"))
```

Comment: @ jared_mamrot thank you very much for your suggestion :) . I need to make a piechart in this case. But the ```theme_minimal()``` definitely helped as it got rid of unnecessary boxes. But the problem still remains, each facet has the labels while i would like to know if there is a way to control where to put the facet labels (either top or bottom) or (left or right).

Comment: You can control the labels in facet_wrap with labeller: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labellers.html