# ggplot, facet, piechart, missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, facet

This is my final dataset. I originally obtained this table by calculating the values separately and doing rbind between females (F) and males (M) from an original bigger dataset.

I am trying to make a handsome piechart, with the percentage labels outside and I've encountered ALL problems possible for which I cannot find a solution.
Notice there is no value A for males in the dataframe.

Dataframe:
sex ms n_ms   n     msPerc     value
1   F  A    1  91 0.01098901  1.098901
2   F  B   18  91 0.19780220 19.780220
3   F  C   65  91 0.71428571 71.428571
4   F  D    7  91 0.07692308  7.692308
5   M  B   11 108 0.10185185 10.185185
6   M  C   86 108 0.79629630 79.629630
7   M  D   11 108 0.10185185 10.185185

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)

n<- c(91, 91 , 91, 91, 108, 108, 108 )
n_ms<-c(1,18,65,7,11,86,11)
sex<- c("F","F","F","F", "M"," M","M")
ms<- c("A","B","C","D","B","C","D")

df <- data.frame(sex, ms, n_ms, n)
df[is.na(df)]<- 0
df$msPerc <- df$n_ms /df$n 
df$value <- 100*df$n_ms /df$n
df$n_ms<- as.integer(df$n_ms) # original big dataframe (doing for replication purposes)
df$n<- as.integer(df$n)

#creating position of labels
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(value))), 
         pos = value/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), value/2, pos))


ms_pie<-ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=msPerc, group=sex,  fill=ms)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  facet_grid(.~ sex) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 9,face = "bold"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#d7191c", "#fdae61", "#abd9e9","#5e3c99"),
                    name="Moulting stage",
                    labels=c("A","B","C","D"))+
#  geom_label(aes(label = percent(msPerc)),
#             position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
#             show.legend = FALSE)
# geom_text(aes(label = percent(msPerc)),size = 3,color = "black", 
#           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
#           show.legend = FALSE)
 geom_label_repel(data = df2,
                  aes(y = pos, label = paste0(value, "%")),
                  size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE)

ms_pie
```

This is what happens...

[image]

What I would like is a piechart like this one from  https://r-charts.com/part-whole/pie-chart-labels-outside-ggplot2/   but including facet_grid in variable "sex".

[image: R charts example]

[image: geom_label]

So far this is the closest I've got. Using geom_label, however my values overlap and I do not know how to separate them either... the joys of being a beginner in R.

I also tried the solutions provided in [ggplot, facet, piechart: placing text in the middle of pie chart slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184188/ggplot-facet-piechart-placing-text-in-the-middle-of-pie-chart-slices)  but coor_polar won't work with scales "free".

I would much appreciate the help.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code I've tried to clean (see comments preceeded by `####`) - this should get you closer:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)              #### using scales for number formatting

n<- c(91, 91 , 91, 91, 108, 108, 108 )
n_ms<-c(1,18,65,7,11,86,11)
sex<- c("F","F","F","F", "M","M","M") #### changed " M" to "M" at last but one element
ms<- c("A","B","C","D","B","C","D")

df <- data.frame(sex, ms, n_ms, n)
df[is.na(df)]<- 0
df$msPerc <- df$n_ms /df$n 
df$value <- 100*df$n_ms /df$n
df$n_ms<- as.integer(df$n_ms) # original big dataframe (doing for replication purposes)
df$n<- as.integer(df$n)

#creating position of labels
df2 <- df %>% group_by(sex) %>% #### you need to group your data by the facets you want to show
    mutate(csum = cumsum(msPerc), #### adjusted example code to use "msPerc"
         pos = msPerc/2 + lag(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), msPerc/2, pos))


ms_pie<-ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=msPerc, group=sex,  fill=ms)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  facet_grid(~sex) +
  theme_void()+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 9,face = "bold"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#d7191c", "#fdae61", "#abd9e9","#5e3c99"),
                    name="Moulting stage",
                    labels=c("A","B","C","D"))+
 geom_label_repel(data = df2,
                  aes(y = pos, label = percent(msPerc, digits = 1)),
                  size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE)

ms_pie
```